# Why does excel's content change when its password is modified?

Tags: excel, dropbox, password-protection, password-encryption

I tested it by assigning an excel a password. This excel was kept in dropbox, and as I assigned a password to the excel, it was entirely downloaded on every comp that it was shared with. Is there a way that I assign the password and the whole file does not get modified? I am sure that it is not an issue with Dropbox as this is what happened with SugarSync as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without deeper knowledge of the internals I still would say NO - Excel has to store your password for this file SOMEHOW, so I'll guess it will be encrypted and stored within your file, hence binary changing it.

Just so you can check this for yourself:

Make a new Workbook and save it.

Open it, just password protect it, and save it as another Workbook (like the first time)

Now compare those with any HEX or Binary-Comparing tool.

Comment: I know the binary will change. Had verified it earlier. Is there a way or may be some other format that doesn't change the binary.

Comment: I would say, that without protecting your dropbox access instead of protecting the file itself, there will be no way to password-protect ANY file, without a binary-change, because you have to store this password somewhere, and thereby change this file. However, when it is more about the "changing" a password without a binary change, you could solve this by using some "access"-file, which would have to have only a constant path instead. So your Excel would check if a given access-file is correct, otherwise deny the access. But the access-file would still change on any password change ;)

Comment: are you suggesting to keep an access file linked to each excel file?

Comment: yes, I hope you see the basic of password protection with this suggestion: you can add some static(!) "access"-file code in every of your excel-file, which you can then protect by a password inside this access-file, which then represents your dynamic(!) storage for your password, which before was inside your excel file. You just must have some place to store the password - there is no way around this.

Comment: just another idea - you could of course try to protect your excel files by some code which uses the windows-environment (like user-name/passwort), but don't ask me how to do this, this is just an idea of what might work and don't change your file.

Comment: was thinking on that track and know how to do it but this is a business decision that I've to take. Ideally I should not rely on Windows that much. That said, it seems the least cumbersome approach for now.

Comment: the main problem with this will, be that you are goning to have to change all the files and you should really be sure on your protection method, because you would have to change it on every file from then on. My stomach squeeqs just thinking about this - wish you luck ;)

Comment: you got the jist of my problem, and btw that sqeeqing is not just limited to your stomach, mine too and in a bigger way i bet ;)

Comment: even worse that i've thousand of files pending to be encrypted before i begin with encrypting rest of the files.

Comment: this somehow does not sound like a very good idea - maybe you should make a new question with your basic problem - like "how to approach this <problem> to match these <requirements>" - there might be someone who knows a nicer way to solve the bigger picture.

Answer (score 2):

Password protection means that the file is encrypted. There is no point in password protecting a file if it is not encrypted. The only other way to prevent people from viewing a file without encrypting it is to restrict access to it.  This can be accomplished by:

1) Modifying the permissions on your computer so that it can only be seen using your password protected account.

2) Not sharing the file with other dropbox users (or share it only with the people you want to see it).

Neither of these is a terribly good security method on it's own. File encryption is always more secure, ideally when used with the above.